# Data copied is not pasting in destination workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a vba macro that is attempting do some light formatting of data in one workbook then paste the formatted data into the bottom of a table in another workbook. For some reason I am getting a Run-time error '1004': PasterSpecial method of Range class failed when it goes to paste and I can't figure out why.

```
Sub Add_Data()
'
' Add_Data Macro
'

' Insert column to the left of column B in raw data
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

' Copy columns A-N in raw data
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range("A2:N" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
    Selection.Copy

' Remove filter from column B of ongoing report
    Windows("Ongoing Report.xlsm").Activate
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("OpenJobs_DATA").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2

' Paste data from raw data at bottom of ongoing report
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

' Filter column B of ongoing report to remove blanks
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("OpenJobs_DATA").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, _
    Criteria1:="<>"
```

Comment: few tips are to avoid using select, active sheet, and make sure to use full reference eg: thisworkbook.worksheets("Sheet1") and set source & destination sheet.

Comment: Could you explain what is happening in ' Insert column to the left of column B in raw data' and why you are doing this. It is inserting a blank column, and later the target data is filtered by it showing no data.

Comment: @VBasic2008 my destination table has a formula that needs to be entered into column B so I decided to insert a row on the raw data workbook so the empty cells are available for the formula to be entered into.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thanks! I am pretty new to vba macros and another user suggested I should avoid using Select if possible so this is just what I needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lose your clipboard data when you unfilter the table in your destination workbook. They unfiltering first then copying the original range. Also, there almost never a good reason to use select. It can slow down your macros.

```
Sub Add_Data()
    Dim home As Worksheet: Set home = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet name 1")
    Dim dest As Worksheet: Set dest = Windows("Ongoing Report.xlsm").Sheets("sheet name 2")

    'Insert column to the left of column B in raw data
    home.Columns("B:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

    'Remove filter from column B of ongoing report
    dest.Sheets("sheet name here").ListObjects("OpenJobs_DATA").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2

    'Copy columns A-N in raw data
    home.Range("A2", Range("A2").SpecialCells(xlEnd).Copy

    'Paste data from raw data at bottom of ongoing report
    dest.Range("A" & dest.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    'Filter column B of ongoing report to remove blanks
    Dest.ListObjects("OpenJobs_DATA").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"
End Sub
```

Untested from my mobile, but hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Dude_Scott. I will give it a try. Thanks for the tip about not using Select. I have very new to vba macros so ill take what I can get!

Answer (score 3):

## Copy Range to Range

- Carefully adjust the values in the constants (`Const`) section.
- It is assumed that the code will be in the workbook containing the
  `RawData` worksheet.

### Tips

- The last or first used cells (rows, columns) are usually calculated
  from the bottom or from the right. I might be wrong here if you have data below `Source Range`.
- Anything containing `Select` and `Active` is best avoided, if possible.
- When pasting values, using `Copy`(`Paste`) is easily (best) avoided.

### The Code

```vb
Sub Add_Data()

    Const cSource As String = "RawData"   ' Source Worksheet Name
    Const cCols As String = "A:N"         ' Source Columns Range Address
    Const cFr As Long = 2                 ' Source/Target First Row Number

    Const cWbTarget As String = "Ongoing Report.xlsm"   ' Target Workbook Name
    Const cTarget As String = "Sheet1"    ' Target Worksheet Name
    Const cTgt As String = "A"            ' Target Column Range

    Dim rngS As Range   ' Source Range
    Dim rngT As Range   ' Target Range

    ' In Source Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSource)
        ' Insert column to the left of column B in raw data.
        .Columns("B:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, _
                CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        ' In Source Columns Range
        With .Columns(cCols)
            ' Calculate and create a reference to Source First Column Last Used
            ' Cell.
            'Set rngS = .Cells(.Row, .Column).End(xlDown)
            Set rngS = .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp)
            ' Calculate and create a reference to Source Range.
            Set rngS = .Rows(cFr).Resize(rngS.Row - cFr + 1)
        End With
    End With

    ' In Target Worksheet
    With Workbooks(cWbTarget).Worksheets(cTarget)
        ' Remove filter from column B of ongoing report
        .ListObjects("OpenJobs_DATA").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2
        ' Calculate and create a reference to Target Column First Empty Cell.
        Set rngT = .Cells(.Rows.Count, cTgt).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        ' Calculate and create a reference to Target Range i.e. adjust the size
        ' to be equal to the size of Source Range.
        Set rngT = rngT.Resize(rngS.Rows.Count, rngS.Columns.Count)
        ' Copy values from Source Range to Target Range.
        rngT = rngS.Value
        ' Filter column B of ongoing report to remove blanks
        .ListObjects("OpenJobs_DATA").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"
    End With

End Sub
```